# Bounty policy for refunding reputation?

Tags: support, bounty

I offered a bounty on [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941499/how-do-you-select-a-rectangular-block-of-numbers-in-the-joe-editor) but it was not answered to my satisfaction. I assumed that if my question was not "answered" to my specifications that I would get my bounty points refunded to my account. If you do not refund the points, that is OK but I would not call it a 'bounty' then. A bounty is only paid if somebody does what the bounty asked for. Thank you for your clarification on this matter.

Comment: Nope, you're not getting it back. See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Actually, the word *originally* had absolutely nothing to do with completing a task in exchange for a reward, and a very common definition of the word still today is just "a generous gift."

Comment: The bounty is the 'price' that attracts the punters; what you really pay for is the attention. A bounty is *advertisement*, not a guarantee you get an answer or your money back.

Comment: The [Oxford Dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bounty#bounty) includes: *A sum paid by the state to encourage trade*. You pay it to *encourage* a good answer. You are not guaranteed one, just like the state was never going to get its money back if the indigo wasn't being produced after all.

Comment: makes perfect sense now...thank you for the clarification

Comment: +1 Not sure why this was downvoted so much. Helped me out, so here's my upvote.

Comment: If I put a bounty on my question and nobody answers my question, why shouldnt the bounty points be returned to me?

What if somebody just answers the question WITHOUT much care or consideration, or even irrelevant answer just to get the rep for bounty, how does the automatic bounty system recognize this? I can also take that advantage with the others.

I think bounty MUST BE be refunded in the following cases- 1. My question has NO answer 2. Somebody just answers the question to get the bounty, not to answer. 3. I myself has the answer and nobody else answered.

Comment: @PeterRaeves I downvoted due to "lack of research effort" as it says on the tooltip. It's trivially searchable, and is in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) as well.

Comment: I don't get how the argument that's used is that you are paying for the attention. How is that a thing? You're not paying for attention, you are paying for someone to take the time to answer your question, with points exchanged as a reward. We can't compare it to some sort of "advertisement". Google never gave me back my money when my ad got a lot of clicks, and kept it when it didn't.

I am sorry, but I just don't buy that argument and would love to know the motivation for this, imo, weird gambling approach on an otherwise straightforward website.[1/2]

Comment: I would get it if it was money, since stackoverflow has a way to earn money this way. But they are points, points are an indication of your contribution to this platform. Stackoverflow doesn't "want" them, they mean something to us, the users. I feel like I must be missing something. Because the whole bountry idea just feels like a betting game. Earning points for contribution makes sense, how does loosing them for providing someone points with a question/challenge makes sense? It's already a bummer when nobody is able to answer the question, at least give me back my points...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a big message on the "Start Bounty" box indicating there are no refunds.  And it's pretty clear in the [bounty info page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) that's how it works.

[image]

Comment: but this is wrong, If I put a bounty on my question and nobody answers my question, why shouldnt the bounty points be returned to me?

Comment: @Tanvir As I was going to tell you on your question, this has already been discussed.  Please use the search(or google, it sometimes tends to work better).  While those duplicates may not be readily available on this meta, they might be on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ . Secondly, posting your questions on these year-old questions won't get you anything, because comments don't bump anything up onto the front page.

Comment: @Tanvir Secondly, you shouldn't have deleted the question; it isn't as if downvotes on meta actually cost you points.  They can mean anything from disagreement to what the tooltip for the downvote says - lack of research.

Comment: I m still learning the stackoverflow policy. I thought "downvoting" costs points. Sorry for reposting but I didnt find the answer to my question anywhere, everyone discussed but no answer from the authority.

Comment: @Tanvir Downvoting does cost points, but only on the main site; on meta sites, like this one, downvoting does not cost points.

Comment: but my answer ...?? whatever I said, isnt it logical ?

Comment: @Tanvir You're not going to get it by leaving comments on a year-old question; either ask it as a question or sit with the answer you got from your research; this has already been discussed to death.

Comment: hmm .. ok.. now I got the answer ... lol

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it a "big" message, since it's the smallest text in the entire dialog. It's literally the "fine print", which pretty much by group consensus *nobody* reads. Maybe we should think about actually making it stand out, instead of the current styling which seems geared more towards making it invisible.

Comment: I wonder if "use" might be better than "offer", since "offer" might give that refundable impression more strongly (offer being retracted). Maybe I'm overthinking it a tad.

Answer (score 4):

> I would get my bounty points refunded to my account

Think of the cost of a bounty as coming from the greater visibility of your question on the featured page, of attracting more people to the question and compete to answer it.

It's like paying to have your advertisement in the local newspaper for a week.

It's still a gamble either way, and you might not get the business/attention you really wanted. But you got the exposure, and that's why it's non-refundable.

I would suggest just awarding it even if the best answer available isn't exactly what you wanted, provided you like it at all. It gives you badges to award it, you don't lose anything at that point, you show people you do award bounties on the questions you ask, etc. But that's just my thoughts on it.

Comment: "It's like paying to have your advertisement in the local newspaper for a week."
I don't agree with this, the main difference is that this "advertisement" is a completely wrong analogy. The newspaper is betting on nobody being able to respond to the ad, which really feels like a weird model to me and discourages me from setting up a Bounty in the first place. It's not like SO earns money with it when nobody answers. It almost has 'gambling' vibe where SO is the dealer that has nothing to earn... Maybe I am missing something, but what's the benefit of loosing point on an unanswered question.