# Where did the bounty go?

Tags: support, bounty

I placed a bounty on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198586/android-build-tools-only-builds-x86-64-no-matter-what-apk-runs-installed-via-ad/43308762#43308762) that I really needed to get fixed.

After a week or so I was able to get it fixed and I thought that the bounty would, as the rules state, go to the accepted answer. But it didn't. Am I forbidden to retrieve my own points even though the only answer was mine or something? Because by the way the rules are stated this would make sense, otherwise it should clearly specify about these kinds of things.

Comment: [Bounties are not refundable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253441/bounty-policy-for-refunding-reputation). Self-awarding would work as a loophole to get a refund, so it makes sense that it isn't allowed.

Comment: I see. Maybe it's a good idea to state it on the rules.

Comment: Once you place a bounty, consider it spent.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot award the bounty to yourself, as it's clearly stated on the [Bounty page in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (**You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.**)

Also, it would implicitly contradict the bounty being non-refundable:

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.

Comment: I should not drink and SO. My apologies.