# Feature request - Non-Popping Bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounty

The current policy about [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) doesn't really make sense or at least the terminology is simply wrong. In my opinion Stack Overflow is more like a [bulletin board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board) instead of a market with its own currency.

> Internet forums are a replacement for traditional bulletin boards.
> (...) An online board can serve the same purpose as a physical bulletin board.

The [support questions on bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support+bounty) answers with [*that's how it works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253442/13629335) or
[*bounty is advertising*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270343/13629335).
But these answers seem contradictory to the [list of reasons for bounties](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/), where drawing attention is just one aspect of a bounty. Bounties make a question more attractive to the community, especially if an answer needs a detailed answer and a lot of research. Which seems to be [the goal of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed,
> high-quality answers to every question about programming.

Therefore a "non-popping" bounty to questions with **no rewardable answer**, that either just doesn't expire and members can offer additional points to the question or a refund for follow up bounties (e.g. +100), should be a [change to this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

In case it isn't clear enough:

1. The normal rules apply for bounties until it expires.
2. After the bounty expires voting or a moderator decides if an extra rule for **well written questions** that have no **rewardable answer** (+3 or manually).

Comment: What do you mean by "pop(p)ing"? PS Your description of your proposal is unclear.

Comment: And what solution do you propose to prevent every single asker with 75+ rep from adding a bounty to every question they ask?

Comment: @philipxy Martijn Pieters stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270343/13629335) the bounty pops even if there is NO answer at all.

Comment: That use of "pop" is figurative/metaphoric language in a certain context, and that context is not repeated here, so it is not clear to say pop here, and please clearly say what you mean.

Comment: @41686d6564 moderators or even the community could decide if this rule should apply.

Comment: Are you suggesting that bounties should be refundable if they receive *no* answers at all? If so, please make that explicit in your question. Currently, your question is a bit unclear about what the feature would look like.

Comment: @cigien updated the question.

Comment: If a bounty is never awarded, then why is it a *bounty* - a reward? The point is that somebody *offers a reward* ("bounty") for answers. And then that reward is given out to an answer. Your proposal seems to be that an answer is never rewarded which then rises the question - why post an answer at all?

Comment: @VLAZ Its all about questions that not recieve a awardable answer. That requiers +3 or manually rewarded.

Comment: That is not at all clear from what you've posted as a question.

Comment: What do we do about questions that should be closed by users who know questions with a bounty cannot be closed? At least with today’s system we just have to wait until the bounty period ends.  Yes; Users absolutely use a bounty to prevent their question from being closed. I have personally seen it.

Comment: @SecurityHound that's a different question.

Comment: @Thingamabobs - No; Your making a feature request; So I am asking if bounties shouldn’t expire then what do we do about improperly bountie questions

Answer (score 13):

Some disambiguation from the Help article you linked:

> Part of what you’re “paying for” with the bounty is to get additional attention for your question, over and beyond what a normal question gets. In that regard, a bounty does not guarantee a response, and reputation refunds are not available if no answers are received as a result of the bounty.

In essence, you're paying for advertisement. Never in the history of ever has there been a refund for an advertisement simply "not working" except under explicit contractual terms. To make things even more explicit, the last line here sets your expectation that you're not guaranteed an answer for the period you advertise your bounty.

Stack Overflow is a massive site and we get nearly 10k questions a day. Allowing someone to take up that attention indefinitely for cheap is honestly disrespectful to the folks who either don't do that or volunteer their time to help here.

Comment: *With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming*. Therefore a **well written question** with **no awardable answer** shouldnt be the case. Dont you think?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no shortage of poorly written questions.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, but especially with a bounty they get downvoted. I've seen -10 and more in this case.

Comment: @Thingamabobs a bounty gets the question more attention, that's the point of it; like [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/3001761) that attention doesn't necessarily lead to a positive response.

Answer (score 5):

You say bounties make questions more attractive and say that's inconsistent with an advertising argument. Isn't the whole purpose of advertising to make you think that you need the product so much that you must go out and buy it immediately?

If bounties could be refunded then we'd end up with complaints from answerers that the question was answered but the bounty was then withdrawn. As it is we already end up with complaints about non-awarding of bounties even though the question asker has no incentive to award the bounty or not. How tempting would it be to keep that lovely rep that you've dangled like a carrot to get your answer?

Bounties are most attractive to answerers in the 24 hours before they expire. If they never expire then their attractiveness is much reduced. Perhaps the OP will never award the bounty no matter what I write in the answer.

Your proposals will make it much less attractive to answer bountied questions. Is that really what you want to achieve?

Answering questions consumes that finite resource, the time of the pool of potential answerers. If they are reading your bountied question, that means they are not reading and answering some other question instead. If you draw people away from answering other questions, you should pay for that attention whether you get an answer or not.

Comment: I updated the question. My proposal should avoid that *hard earned points* pop on **well written questions with a bounty** that has **no rewardable answer**.

Comment: Everyone asking thinks their question is well written. Unfortunately, voting suggests that's simply not the case. People bounty errant nonsense and waste the time of people reading it

Comment: The main problem of the bounty is that you can lose your (only) points to a question that may never been answered. For exampel, I only made an account to SO for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050496/nested-class-factory-with-tkinter) and I imagine not getting an answer and cant reuse the points for a follow up bounty or people who think this question is worth answering cant use my point to make the question more attactive. Members would just wasting points.

Comment: Except you did get an answer to that question, in fact you got more than one so in this case the bounty got you what you wanted. You can't pay for two different things with the same money, you need  to go out and earn some more.

Comment: Now I want to edit the title to be Feature request - Carrot Bounty